# JavaScript RegExp returns false in every valid and invalid inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In my JSP page I have one table in that one of the column is for the Time shown in the HH:mm format and the datatype is String (I converted it from Date to String in server). Now I am applying the Inline table row editing using the Jquery plugin Tabledit.

While I edit the column and before sending to the server I am checking it with RegExp.

```js
var inTime = [];
var timeRegEx = new RegExp("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|0[0-9]|([1-5][0-9]))$");
inTime[1] = "14:34";
if (timeRegEx.test(inTime[1])) {
  alert("Matched");
  //return true;
} else {
  alert("Not Mateched");
  //return false;
}
```

I have checked the validity of the RegExp in some onilne resources and it is correct.

But in my case in every valid and invalid input it always goes to the else block.

And the more thing is that the while I print the value of the **inTime[1] in alert**. it gives the output like : **14%3A13**

So I also replaced the **: with %3A** in RegExp but it also not worked.

So please tell me where I am going the wrong and what is the correct solution.

Edit:

Here  : interpreted as %3A so may be this creates the problem.

Here inTime is array which get values from the table row.

Comment: I placed your code in a runnable snippet where it works absolutely fine. Could you please show us more relevant code, and also check your console for errors. Note that it would appear that if your value is `14%3A13` then it has been URL encoded somehow. That would explain why the code fails.

Comment: Try this: `if (decodeURIComponent(timeRegEx.test(inTime[1]))) {`

Comment: `%3A` is html entity of `:` decode your string before test it with regex.

Comment: @Toto I think you are right. but what how to decode? please provide some hint.

Comment: @spanky gave you the answer just above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861130/javascript-regexp-returns-false-in-every-valid-and-invalid-inputs#comment78680355_45861130

Comment: @Toto decoding also not worked.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I checked the console but there is no error.

Comment: Have make a CW answer, it seems to work. May be you have some other strange characters i the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question that the array variable inTime[1] get the data from the HTML table. It takes the: as the %3A, so it creates the problem to test the RegExp.

@Spanky give me hint to try decodeURIComponent(timeRegEx.test(inTime[1])) but it also not worked for me.

So I have slight modify his solution and applied the decodeURIComponent() to only inTime[1] Variable. This worked for me.

The solution code snippet is as follow:

```js
var inTime = [];
var timeRegEx = new RegExp("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|0[0-9]|([1-5][0-9]))$");
inTime[1] = "14%3A34";
if (timeRegEx.test(decodeURIComponent(inTime[1]))) {
  console.log("Matched");
  //return true;
} else {
  console.log("Not Mateched");
  //return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var inTime = [];
var timeRegEx = new RegExp("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|0[0-9]|([1-5][0-9]))$");
inTime[1] = "14%A334";
if (decodeURIComponent(timeRegEx.test(inTime[1]))) {
  console.log("Matched");
  //return true;
} else {
  console.log("Not Mateched");
  //return false;
}
```

Comment: @AkshayPethani: Error comes from another part of the script. You could show us more context.

Answer (score 0):

Does this suite your needs?

```js
var regex = /^[12]?\d:[012345]\d$/,
    tests = [
       '56:12',
       '03:68',
       '2:49',
       '12:59',
       '23:00',
       'abcs',
       '12,23'
    ];
    
tests.forEach(test => {
  var isValid = regex.test(test);
  console.log(`is ${test} valid: ${isValid}`);
});
```